# Distribution of the size of overlap between two random samples with duplicates?

Tags: distributions, probability, statistical-significance, sampling, hypergeometric-distribution

Similar to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/267/how-do-i-calculate-if-the-degree-of-overlap-between-two-lists-is-significant), I want to know if the overlap between two samples is significant.  However, my items are not unique; I have $c$ distinct colors of items, there are $m_i$ items of color $i: (1<i<c) $, and $N=\sum m_i$ items total.  Does this make a difference?

I have figured out that drawing one sample of *n* items (without replacement) follows the [multivariate hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution).  My question is: given two samples of sizes $n_A$ and $n_B$, what is the probability that they share exactly $k$ distinct items in common?  And really, I'd like my samples to be *sets*, so I have at most one item of each color in my samples, though this seems to be a harder problem.

Comment: Can you distinguish the items or just their colors?  Say, for the blue items, do you know how many are just in sample 1, how many are just in sample 2 and how many are in both?  Or do you just know the total number of blue balls and of the numbers in each of sample 1 and sample 2?

Comment: I cannot distinguish between two items of the same color.